Vba macro to connect to worksheets from a table
My issue is I’m trying to connect to workbooks from a table which contains their address called workbook paths, the macro should loop through and connect to the worksheet however I’m getting the error no isam installed, can anyone help? Here is my Code.
Sub ConnectToWorkbooksInTable()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim wbPath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblRow As ListRow

    ' Set the worksheet containing the table
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("helper")

    ' Set the table
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("address")

    ' Loop through each row in the table
    For Each tblRow In tbl.ListRows
        ' Retrieve workbook path from the first column of the current row
        wbPath = tblRow.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value

        ' Check if wbPath is not empty
        If wbPath <> "" Then
            ' Create the connection string
            sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                          "Data Source=" & wbPath & ";" & _
                          "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"

            ' Create the ADODB connection object
            Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

            ' Attempt to open the connection
            On Error Resume Next
            conn.Open sConnString
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Error opening connection to " & wbPath & ": " & Err.Description
                Err.Clear
            Else
                MsgBox "Successfully connected to workbook: " & wbPath
                conn.Close
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' Clean up
            Set conn = Nothing
        End If
    Next tblRow

    MsgBox "Finished processing all workbooks."
End Sub

I tried the above code and single speech marks but it didn’t work

What are the addresses?  Are these sheets in another Excel file?  Can you show us a couple of examples?

The addresses are in a table called WorkbookPaths, they are dynamically downloaded to the table it’s just one column, with a regular c:\users etc I can’t show an example, as the table includes some work numbers I can’t show

On which line do you get the error? Are all values of the objects/variables valid (e.g. wbPath is correct)?

I should add I have tried this with a direct file path as well

sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & wbPath & ";" & _
"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
This one Shrotter

You still haven't said what the addresses are.  Are these literally file system paths to Excel files?

The addresses are located in a table….they are the system file paths to the excel files
